# Trouble Installing NVIDIA GTX 560 SE

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics

The latest Nvidia drivers claim support for this card, but when I try to install them, my computer won't boot.

The card shows up in `lspci` as:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1208] (rev a1)
```

The only way I can boot properly is setting the **nomodeset** boot option on.

Normally you would do that once in order to install the drivers, but once I install the drivers I can no longer boot and I am greeted with a blank screen.

I've also followed the instructions [here](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-remove-nouveau-drivers-ubuntu), but they didn't help.